# How to limit entities with the same foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE a {
  id PRIMARY KEY
};

CREATE TABLE b {
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  a_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (a_id) REFERENCES a(id)
}

CREATE TABLE c {
  id PRIMARY KEY,
  b_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (b_id) REFERENCES b(id)
```

I want to get top 30 entities from `b` order by `COUNT(c.id)` eg

```
SELECT b.id, a_id FROM b
JOIN c ON b_id = b.id
GROUP BY b.id
ORDER BY COUNT(c.id)
LIMIT 30;
```

But be sure that there will be not more than 6 entities with the same `a_id`

Comment: Do you only want 6 or eliminate those with more than 6 period ?

Comment: I'm curious why your b_id references a(id) rather than b(id). If that was meant to be, i would have called it a_id instead. Also, it might be helpful to see some sample data from each table.

Comment: Are you wanting to limit the results of the query or limit what can be stored in the database?

Comment: @CSS ,I mean `b(id)`

Comment: @DStanley I want to limit results.

Comment: @Frisbee i whant something like
    |   1 |  1 |
    |   2 |  1 |
    ...
    |   6 |  1 |
    | 123 |  2 |
    ...

Comment: Fix the question and answer by question on how you the result limited

Comment: You question has nothing to do with foreign keys...